# How to create Roo Shell project in SpringSource Tool Suite?

Tags: java, spring-roo

Just have created a Spring project in STS and shown the view 'Roo Shell'. It's dialog has a link which opens a dialog 'Roo Shell Project Selection'. User is asked to select among a list of project one to work with the shell. Problem is that the list is empty.

Is there a way to create a Roo Shell project or RooShellify an existing one?

Don't want to install standalone Spring Roo until current evaluation passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project -> SpringTools -> Add Roo Nature

Then the project is listed in the Roo Shell project selection dialog.

Or even better:

File -> New -> Other -> Spring Template Project and choose 'Roo Web App (based on...)'

Comment: i'm looking at STS 2.5.2, and i can tell you i don't see a SpringTools  or anything mentioning Roo anywhere, please check my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947982/springsource-sts-2-5-2-how-do-i-open-the-roo-shell